# How is Powershell handling pipe and command line input at the same time?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

I have a script that I'm testing in Powershell 7.3. An example of the construction:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ( 
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$DomainName,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [pscredential]$Credential,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]$IPv4Address,
    [string]$userName,
    [string]$log
)
Process {
    "***"
    "ComputerName:$ComputerName"
    "DomainName:$DomainName"
    if ($Credential) { "Credential:" + $Credential.username }else { "No credential" }
    "IP Address:$IPv4Address"
    "User name:$UserName"
}
```

I can pipe in one or more objects and it works fine. I can specify one or more properties as arguments at the command line and it works fine. I can specify up to one less than all of the properties as arguments as well as pipe in objects and it will work fine with the command line arguments overriding the object properties every time the process block runs. However, if I do this but with all 4 pipeable parameters specified at the command line, I get only an error message for each run of the process block:

> "Remove-RemoteUser: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

In this script, one would probably not do both at the same time, except maybe for the credential. But, I might use this construction in the future. So, as it might not be obvious to the user that they can't do this or why they get that error message, is there any way to detect this condition within the script so that I can abort and give a useful error message?
Example command line that gives the error:

> $myVM|remove-remoteuser -user bogus -domainName command.domain -credential $myCred -computername "command computer" -IPv4Address 0.0.0.0

If I remove any one of the 4 parameters that allows pipeline input, then I do not receive an error. For example:

```
> $myVM|remove-remoteuser -user bogus -domainName command.domain -credential $myCred -computername "command computer"
***
ComputerName:command computer
DomainName:command.domain
Credential:My.Test.Domain\TestUser
IP Address:192.168.176.11
User name:bogus
```

Additional details

```
> $myvm
hostName     : Myhost
domainName   : My.Test.Domain
ComputerName : Myhost.My.Test.Domain
credential   : System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
IPv4Address  : 192.168.176.11
```

Secondarily, does anyone know how to take arguments at the command line (at the same time as from the pipeline) and make the script run as if those command line arguments were just another object in the pipeline? I probably wouldn't want to use a complex structure to do that, just curious.

Comment: "However, if I do this but with all 4 pipeable parameters specified at the command line, I get only an error message for each run of the process block:" can you add how to reproduce this error? you script works perfectly fine piping an object binding to the 4 parameters

Comment: It might help if you also included an example of the actual command line you're trying that's generating that error.

Comment: Also unless I'm misunderstanding something, I'm seeing 6 parameters, not 4, and think since you're specifying `[string]$userName` and `[string]$log` explicitely as strings you also need to specify `[parameter]` before those two as well.

Comment: It sounds like you’re trying to pipe and specify to the same parameter. That won’t work.

Comment: Yes, Doug, that was the second question. As you can see, it does work. But, it doesn't get treated as though the command line arguments are an additional object piped in. Instead, the command line argument replaces the property in the piped in objects.